# In an Oh My Zsh customized prompt, what is the number with the white background?

Tags: git, shell, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Oh My Zsh on macOS and, while working in a Git-versioned directory, I have three different information fields in the prompt:

1. the current folder [blue background]
2. the local branch (+ahead/-behind) [green background], and
3. the remote branch (+ahead/-behind) [teal background]

It usually works just fine, except that now I have an additional section, the part with the white backgroud:
[image: Oh My ZSH custom prompt]

I tried running `git status` to understand what that "+9" could possibly mean:

> On branch bootstrap-adjustments
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/bootstrap-adjustments'.
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

I also tried looking into the `git-prompt` plugin [source code](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git-prompt/git-prompt.plugin.zsh) but I wasn't able to find that section.

Does anyone know what that "+9" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [A fellow Vimer](https://twitter.com/ktonga) on Twitter:

The +9 is the number of stashes in the repo.

Found out by running: `git stash list`.